# `inline-block` behaving like `block`

Tags: html, css

This couldn't be any simpler, but somehow I can't figure it out. I want an image to be on the far left, and a series of buttons to be right aligned as a group. Everything should appear on one row.

```css
    #titleframe {width:100%; height:85px; display:inline-block;}
    
    #logo {width:256px; height:85px; margin-left:20px;}
    
    #logo img {width:100%; height:auto;}
    
    #menu-buttons-container {display:inline-block; float:right; height:40px;}
    
    #menu-buttons button {width:75px; height:40px;}
```

```html
    <div id="titleframe">
        <div id="logo"><img src="https://..."></div>
        <div id="menu-buttons-container">
         <button>text</button>
         <button>text</button>
         <button>text</button>
         <button>text</button>
         <button>text</button>
        </div>  
    </div>
```

But when this renders, I get the logo where i want it, and the buttons are indeed right aligned. However, the button row is placed one row *below* the logo. It's supposed to be on the same row - that's what `inline-block` is for, right? It's rendering as if I were using `block` rather than `inline-block`.

Why aren't my buttons placed on the same row as the image is? There is plenty of width for everything to fit.

Thanks!

Comment: What browser is this in? Have you tried others? It looks correct for me in the preview above (using Firefox on Mac.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make #logo inline-block too.

https://jsfiddle.net/7b91bo0p/

```
#logo {width:256px; height:85px; margin-left:20px;display:inline-block}
```

Comment: That was it. Thanks! (I'll accept as soon as SO let's me).